# Normalizing time series measurements

Tags: python, time-series, normalization

I have read the following sentence:

> Figure 3 depicts how the pressure develops during a touch event. It
>   shows the mean over all button touches from all users. To account for
>   the different hold times of the touch events, the time axis has been
>   normalized before averaging the pressure values.

They have measured the touch pressure over touch events and made a plot. I think normalizing the time axis means to scale the time axis to 1s, for example. But how can this be made? Let's say for example I have a measurement which spans 3.34 seconds (1000 timestamps and 1000 measurements). How can I normalize this measurement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to normalize you data you can do as you suggest and simply calculate:

```
z_i=\frac{x_i-min(x)}{max(x)-min(x)}
```

(Sorry but i cannot post images yet but you can visit [this](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=z_i%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx_i-min(x)%7D%7Bmax(x)-min(x)%7D) )

where zi is your i-th normalized time data, and xi is your absolute data.

An example using numpy:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.random.rand(10) # generate 10 random values
normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))

print(x,normalized)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this will normalize the scale of x to lie between zero and one and not the time series. Let's say x is the data and y are the timestamps belonging to x. I would like to normalize x so that the timestamps span e.g. 1s.